# htaccess force redirect http except wp-admin, wp-login.php and specific url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been struggling with .htaccess redirects with no luck.

I want all my site pages to be force redirected to **http** except wp-admin, wp-login.php and one below url.

https://www.mysite.ie/grupai/grupai-foirm/

Could you please help.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# if not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# and not wp-admin, etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php [NC]

# redirect to https 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**change from wordpress database table wp-options site url and home url**

```
(e.g) http://localhost/wordpress
```

Comment: can i see .httaccess file

Comment: It is just standard WordPress .htaccess file. I need to add rules to achieve what I explained in my question.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your-folder-name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your-folder-name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress  if project inside a folder

Answer (score 0):

If you fail with htaccess, you can try to do that via WP itself.
By default all website works with HTTP.
And this code detects current protocol and current page, if they need to be redirected, so it redirects them to https.

```
add_action('init','redirector',0);
add_action('admin_init','redirector',0);
function redirector(){
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
if ($protocol=='http://' and
(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'wp-login')===false or
strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'wp-admin')===false or
strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'grupai/grupai-foirm')===false)){
header("location: https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
die();
}
}
```